# ios swift, how to Convert NSMutableDictionary to nsdictionary

Tags: objective-c, swift

i know obc is

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"value", @"key"] mutableCopy];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:mutableDict];
```

but swift,  how to Convert  NSMutableDictionary to nsdictionary

Comment: `let imm = NSDictionary(dictionary: mutable)` but why use it anyway? Use the Swift `Dictionary` instead!

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/)?

Answer (score 1):

let imm = NSDictionary(dictionary: mutable) but why use it anyway? Use the Swift Dictionary instead! – luk2302

thanks luk2302.

because i use obc +  swift in one project,  many old code in this project using   "Convert NSMutableDictionary to nsdictionary".

Answer (score 1):

You can convert in swift using following:
NSDictionary.init(dictionary: dictDocumentLines)